# Property 'clientX' does not exist on type 'Event'. Angular2 Directive

Tags: angular, events, typescript, event-listener, angular2-directives

I'm trying to listen to the X position of my mouse in an Angular2 Directive like this:

```
@HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
onMousemove(event: Event): void  { 
  console.log(event.clientX)
}
```

but I get the error

> Property 'clientX' does not exist on type 'Event'.

This is odd because this listener

```
@HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
onMousemove(event: Event): void  { 
  console.log(event)
}
```

logs out an event object

[image]

**Why can I not access `event.clientX`?**

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Change the parameter type

```
onMousemove(event: MouseEvent): void  { 
  console.log(event.clientX)
}
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, I tried with several different types, including `MouseEvent` that is the one I get in my console.log() but it keeps saying: `Property 'layerY' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent'`

Comment: Interesting. It not a standardized property but according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerY all browsers support it. Check your browsers changelog if it was discontinued there.